# SQL Convert output from decimal to comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql query (Eg. select amount from purchase_order) which outputs something like 123.45. Instead I want it output it like 123,45 (German numeral system). How do I do that?

Comment: Does this have to be done on the database?  Or can you just change the formatting client-side?

Comment: `amount` is a string or a number in the table definition ?

Comment: And what is the database...MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle, etc. ?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: needs to be done on the db side because there are calculations involved after this

Comment: @FabienTheSolution: amount is a number, MS-SQL db

Comment: And what is the version ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

**use stuff string  function to replae the(.) by (,)**

```
 select stuff(amount ,charindex('.', amount),1,',')
 from  purchase_order
```

Comment: this was just 1 example...the output can range from 6-8 digits before decimal

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `REPLACE` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
SELECT REPLACE(amount, '.',',') FROM purchase_order
```

Keep in mind that this will replace **all** values that match, so in this case all periods would be replaced with commas

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace function (Convert to char beforehand,if necessary). Example:

```
REPLACE ( TO_CHAR(amount), '.', ',')`.
```

Even better: set your locale properly. Thereafter all number lexicalisations should follow the  respective convention.

There may also be the option to decide on a case-by-case basis. Example (Oracle syntax; you specify 2 characters, the decimal point and the group separator. For German, this would be `,.`, for English `.,`, resp.):

```
TO_CHAR ( amount, '9999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''' )
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2012, you have the [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) function.

There is no need to do this on the db side even if calculations are involved after this...

So try this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87af0/3)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_order
    ([amount] money)
;

INSERT INTO purchase_order
    ([amount])
VALUES
    (123.45)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select FORMAT ( amount, 'G', 'de-de' ) AS 'amount'
from purchase_order
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87af0/3/0)**:

```
|   AMOUNT |
|----------|
| 123,4500 |
```

Answer (score 0):

> "needs to be done on the db side because there are calculations involved after this"

Then *don't worry about the format*.  In the database it's just a number.  Any calculations will apply to the number itself regardless of how it's observed.  Formatting only gets applied when you view the number.  Don't do any formatting prior to calculations.

Do formatting at the very last layer - the UI/reporting layer.